# C++ vector iteration: const vs. const auto vs. no const

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a `vector <string> v{"First sentence.", "Second sentence.", "Third sentence."};` that I want to concatenate while inserting an end-line delimiter.

I don't understand the difference between these three iteration methods:

```
string build()
{
    string ret;

    for (string s: v) {
        ret += (s + "\n");
    }
    return ret;
}

string build()
{
    string ret;

    for (const string s: v) {
        ret += (s + "\n");
    }
    return ret;
}

string build()
{
    string ret;

    for (const auto &s: v) {
        ret += (s + "\n");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

What should I use or not use, and depending on what?

Comment: Please ask a more specific question, and post working code... [MCVE]

Comment: The third version uses reference, no additional copy.

Comment: The first two versions will make a copy of strings stored in the vector, which is inefficient.

Comment: One makes copy of string and you allowed to change copy, another is like the first one but you are not allowed to change copy, third gives you reference directly to the string in vector but you are not allowed to change it.

Comment: Loop body is not optimal as well. `(s + "\n")` will create a temporary string on each iteration. It should be `ret.append(s); ret.push_back('\n');`

Comment: use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: If you don't want to use the strings again, you should also consider `auto&& s` - see Petr Zemek's article [Auto Type Deduction in Range-Based For Loops](https://blog.petrzemek.net/2016/08/17/auto-type-deduction-in-range-based-for-loops/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) overloads utilize the [range based loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). The first overload accepts parameter `s` of type `std::string` by value. It makes a copy of each of the elements in a container. Changes made to `s` are not reflected to actual container elements.

The second overload accepts parameter `s` of type `std::string` by value but makes it a read-only due to a `const` specifier. There can not be changes to `s`.

The third overload accepts parameter `s` by reference to const. It uses the [auto specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) which deduces the `s` to be of type `std::string`. No changes allowed, no copies made.

As-is you can do without the first two. Here is the [Const Correctness FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#overview-const).

Answer (score 2):

- `auto x` when you want to work with copies.
- `auto &x` when you want to work with original items and probably you gonna modify them.
- `auto const &x` when you want to work with original items and will not modify them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in terms of result.

1. Allows you to modify the string, but you should pass it with reference for not to modify a copy.
2. Does not allow you to modify the string, this is done for a read-only access.
3. auto is for convenience, no difference with the second case in this case. Usually autos are used in range cycles to avoid long typing, for instance `std::vector<std::map<std::string, long>>::iterator`